# matplotlib: Draw ontop of image - keep colorbar range

Tags: matplotlib

I want to draw into the same figure while keeping the colorbar and it's range. How to do that?

Sounds easy, but apparantly it's not:

```
cbar = plt.colorbar()
cbar.set_clim(vmin=-1.0, vmax=1.0)
plt.show(block=False) 

for i in range(num_maps):
  plt.imshow(img)  # img to draw the data ontop of
  data = all_data[:,:,i]
  plt.imshow(data, alpha=0.5)  # data to draw
  plt.pause(0.5)
```

I assume because I first plot the image my colobar range gets destroyed as it has values between [0..255]. Any idea how to suppress that behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I have to call `colobar()` after setting the range...

```
plt.set_clim(vmin=-1.0, vmax=1.0) # <--- swaped
plt.colorbar()  # <--- swaped 
plt.show(block=False) 

for i in range(num_maps):
  plt.imshow(img)  # img to draw the data ontop of
  data = all_data[:,:,i]

  # imshow resets the colorbar -> again specify vmin and vmax
  plt.imshow(data, alpha=0.5, vmin=-1.0, vmax=1.0)  
  plt.pause(0.5)
```

now it works...